# Omit default controller namespace for package controllers' `redirect()->action()` method

Tags: php, controller, namespaces, package, laravel-5.6

First off, the issue/question arose with Laravel 5.6 and PHP 7.4.10. I know that 'magic strings' for controller calls have been deprecated as of recent Laravel versions, but I'm interested in the underlying infrastructure in this question.

**PREREQUISITES**

Suppose I have two folders: `project` and `core`.

- `project` contains a freshly installed laravel project;
- `core` contains some package-like structure of namespaces and classes (not actually a package in the laravel sense), which is being autoloaded by the `project`.

For a minimal working example, you can see [the last commit of the repository I published about this](https://dev.editcreation.com/david/package-controller-redirect-to-action-mwe/commit/5878f9b70db318e9e16c33066f596b4e79bdb01d). I'm going to post the main files' contents here as well, but you can actually reproduce and play around with the sample projects yourself.

Basically the concept is pretty standard, much like a package: I want to have some reusable logic inside of my core with some default implementations. In the project I may or may not overwrite some of the functions, but for the sake of the question's simplicity, my `core` only defines a `Fruit` module (just a folder with a namespace) containig three files:

- `fruit_routes.php`

```
<?php

Route::get('/pear', 'FruitController@pear');
Route::get('/apple', 'FruitController@apple');
```

- `FruitController` (**This is where the question is focused**)

```
<?php
namespace CORE\Fruit;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class FruitController extends Controller
{
    public function pear()
    {
        //if we call the action '\CORE\Fruit\FruitController@apple' instead, it works :)
        return redirect()->action('FruitController@apple', ['message' => "No pears available! :( "]);
    }
    
    public function apple(Request $request)
    {
        return $request->message . "There you have an apple!";
    }
}
```

- `FruitServiceProvider`

```
<?php
namespace CORE\Fruit;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class FruitServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        /*
         * Map routes from our Fruit module to the controller's namespace
         */
        $this->app->router->namespace('CORE\Fruit')->group(__DIR__."/fruit_routes.php");
    }
}
```

And then in the `project` I simply include the following two lines:

- `composer.json`

```
{
    //..
    "autoload": 
        //...
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "CORE\\" : "../core"
        }
    },
}
```

- `config/app.php` in `$providers` array

```
/*
 * Package Service Providers...
 */
CORE\Fruit\FruitServiceProvider::class,
```

Again, for the full sample structure and contents, refer to the [MWE repo](https://dev.editcreation.com/david/package-controller-redirect-to-action-mwe/commit/5878f9b70db318e9e16c33066f596b4e79bdb01d).

**THE QUESTION**

Although the namespace for the controller classes has been explicitly declared from the `FruitServiceProvider`'s `register()` method for the `fruit_routes.php` file, Laravel still fails to recognize that same namespace when using `rediret()->action()` from within those same controllers.

In the given `FruitController` you can see:

```
return redirect()->action('FruitController@apple');
```

and this will fail with `Action App\Http\Controllers\FruitController@apple not defined.`

As you can see, Laravel still searches for the controller inside the current project's default controller namespace (in this case: `App\Http\Controllers`)

Fortunately, passing the fully qualified name of the controller solves the issue:

```
return redirect()->action([self::class, 'apple']);
//Or alternativelly, but really clumsy:
//return redirect()->action('\Core\Fruit\FruitController@apple'); //notice the slash at the beginning
```

I have the suspicion that I must somehow also inform the `redirect()` helper (and actually, the underlying `Redirect` facade) that I want it to reference the controllers inside of my `CORE\Fruit` namespace whenever called from within that namespace... Or what would be the right approach? Is that desired behavior and am I missing something? And again, as mentioned in the beginning, I know that 'magic strings' are not the best practice and the most beloved feature of Laravel, but I really want to understand how things work in this scenario.

I also found [this issue on github](https://github.com/nWidart/laravel-modules/issues/663) with a realted topic, but no answer there as well. As for people who are about to comment 'just avoid using magic strings', I'm stuck with a project I inherited and rewriting all of the core's magic string controller references is really not an option I would love to embrace.

Any insight is appreaciated! Many many thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm quite unfamiliar with Laravel, so just posting this as a comment, but the [array form](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/redirects#redirecting-controller-actions) seems like the preferred way of doing this now (and it also looks a lot cleaner). Simply use `__CLASS__` or `ClassName::class` (import it first with a `use` statement if it's an external one).

Comment: @Jeto I know, I know, I would prefer that myself, too. You caught me just in the middle of editing my post with that comment; but the thing is I'm actually stuck with an inherited project which I just don't want to start rewriting in that regard...

Comment: Could you alter [this](https://dev.editcreation.com/david/package-controller-redirect-to-action-mwe/blob/master/project/app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php#L17)? (Again, no idea about whether that would be considered an acceptable practice, but that *seems* to be the base namespace you're looking to have changed.)

Comment: @Jeto Thank you for the attention. Unfortunately, this should remain as it is, because it is related to the `project`'s controllers, which my controller has nothing in common with. I namely want my `FruitController` to be independant of the project importing the `Fruit` module and so to speak live in its own namespace inside the `core`. But I can't find the way to tell laravel to `redirect()->action()` to that separate namespace.